# Document Moved 201 Remove from WebResponse

Tags: c#, woocommerce

I use .NET 4.61. Can I get the response from https://1106-7916.el-alt.com/wp-json/wc/v2/products/407 instead of https://1106-7916.el-alt.com/wp-json/wc/v2/products, which causes a redirect? Can I add code to BuildRequest, shown below, to get that response automatically?

I am using the `WooCommerce REST API` to create products. Here is my request:

```
POST-https://1106-7916.el-alt.com/wp-json/wc/v2/products?consumer_key=X

{"attributes":[{"name":"Color","visible":true,"variation":true,"options":["Red","Blue","Green","Orange"]},{"name":"Size","visible":true,"variation":true,"options":["S","M","L"]}],"title":"FooFoo","sku":"TestCreateProductWoo1026","description":"Test","categories":[],"tags":[],"type":"variable"}
```

Here is the response:

```html
HTTP/1.1 201 Created
Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0
Allow: GET, POST
Location: https://1106-7916.el-alt.com/wp-json/wc/v2/products/407
<head><title>Document Moved</title></head>
<body><h1>Object Moved</h1>This document may be found <a HREF="https://1106-7916.el-alt.com/wp-json/wc/v2/products/407">here</a></body>{"id":407,"name":"Product","slug":"product"}
```

Here is my code:

```
    private string BuildRequest(string path, IDictionary<string, string> query, HttpMethodTypes httpMethod, object body)
    {
        string pathAndQuery = BuildParameters(path, query);

        string resultData = string.Empty;
        HttpWebRequest myHttpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(pathAndQuery);
        myHttpWebRequest.Accept = "application/json";
        myHttpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
        myHttpWebRequest.UserAgent = "JMA Web Technologies";
        myHttpWebRequest.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
        SetHeaders(myHttpWebRequest);

        if (httpMethod != HttpMethodTypes.GET)
            myHttpWebRequest.Method = httpMethod.ToString();

        SetResponseBody(body, myHttpWebRequest);

        WebResponse httpResponse = myHttpWebRequest.GetResponse();
        Stream responseStream = httpResponse.GetResponseStream();
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream);
        resultData = reader.ReadToEnd();
        responseStream.Close();
        httpResponse.Close();
        return resultData;
    }
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: The endpoint you are calling (the one returning 201)? Is it yours? Are you able to change it?

Comment: Yes, this endpoint appears when I create a product. Here are the docs: https://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/#create-a-product

Comment: OK, so you don't control the endpoint. It is a pre-existing endpoint that you are calling. In that case, I don't understand your question. You called the endpoint. It did its work. What is the issue?

Comment: I am trying to parse the JSON into an object. Since I return the object moved in the HTML, I cannot parse it. I adjusted my question.

Comment: So you want the JSON as available at https://1106-7916.el-alt.com/wp-json/wc/v2/products/407 ?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. I adjusted my question.

Comment: the redirect should be happening. can you verify that your `HttpWebRequest` is doing the redirects? is this .net core or .net framework?

Comment: @DanielA.White I don't believe it is a redirect (since it is a 201). Redirects start with 3.